# AngularJs plunker not working? New to Plunker

Tags: angularjs, plunker

I am relatively new to plunker, what am I doing wrong? There are errors in the console, and the live preview is not working. The code works perfectly fine in my localhost.

Here's the link for it. http://plnkr.co/edit/cZ48oeBBDthtVqXMRJPy?p=preview

```
    <html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.1/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="3.1.1" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="less.js@*" data-semver="2.6.1" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/2.6.1/less.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.less" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <div class="container">
      <!-- Parent scope -->
      <div class="">
        <div prevent="" visible="isVisible" object-data="objectData">
          <table class="datatable">
            <tbody>
              <tr ng-repeat="t in templateData">
                <td class="haseebtesting" ng-click="current.selected = t; confusedFunction(t)" id="{{'test ' + $index}}">{{t.templateName}}</td>
                <td>{{t.templatePath}}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <div ng-show="isVisible" class="parented">
            <form class="haseebform">
              <input type="text" ng-model="objectData.entername" placeholder="Enter name" />
              <br />
              <input type="text" ng-model="objectData.entercomment" placeholder="Enter comment" />
              <input type="button" class="btn btn-info" ng-click="addT(objectData)" value="Submit" />
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: The code is calling `script.js` twice: once in the head and again in the body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[plnkr edit](https://plnkr.co/edit/N2JOhPDKlfJA8a0jNlar?p=info)

I started it without errors.

script code:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/2.7.2/less.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to move the jquery script above the angular script. When angular loads, if jquery is not present,  jqlite is used instead even if jquery is loaded subsequently.

Comment: Hi. I tried, still does not work. http://plnkr.co/edit/cZ48oeBBDthtVqXMRJPy?p=preview